# Mongo numbericOrdering not sorting number padded with 0

Tags: mongodb, mongoose

I am storing numbers as string, because for my system "001" is not equal to "1" or "01" as I use this as id for data objects. But, I want to show my data ordered by this id ( lets call myModelId ). To achieve that I tried to use mongoose collation feature [numericOrdering](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/collation/), but by my tests it do not sort right when there are numbers stored with zeros to the left. Can someone help me ?

My mongodb is 4.0.18 and mongoose is 5.9.19

Example code:

```
    ...

    MyModel.find({},{}, { sort: "+myModelId", locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true }, function (err, list) {

            if (err) {

                return res.status(500).send({ success: false, error: err.message });

            } else {

                return res.status(200).json({success: true, rows: list});

            }
    });
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For some unknown reason when I pipeline the query configs the numericOrdering works as expected.

```
   ...

MyModel.find({}).sort({ myModelId: 1 }).collation({ locale: "en_US", numericOrdering: true }).exec( function (err, list) {

        if (err) {

            return res.status(500).send({ success: false, error: err.message });

        } else {

            return res.status(200).json({success: true, rows: list});

        }
});
```